# flutter :Inkwell not working in stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a stack viewpager [by this reference](https://betterprogramming.pub/custom-horizontal-scroll-with-pageview-builder-10604dad3b30) :

```
  body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      
      Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: _itemWidth,
              child: FractionallySizedBox(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => debugPrint("clicked"), ///this part not works
                child: PageViewItem(
                  index: _firstItemIndex,
                  width: _itemWidth,
                  url: model[_firstItemIndex],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 250,
          child: PageView.builder(
            padEnds: false,
            controller: _controller,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Opacity(
                opacity: index <= _firstItemIndex ? 0 : 1,
                child: PageViewItem(
                  index: index,

                  width: _itemWidth,
                  url: model[index],

                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: model.length,
          ),
        ),
      ],
),
    ],
```

in this part :

```
 InkWell(
    onTap: () => debugPrint("clicked"), ///this part not works
    child: PageViewItem(
      index: _firstItemIndex,
      width: _itemWidth,
      url: model[_firstItemIndex],
      ),
    ),
```

onTap Not working because is under `PageView.builder` . do you have any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Could something like this perhaps be a way forward? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66244349/propagate-click-behind-a-widget

Comment: Yes with `GestureDetector` is possible to fix that but I mistook a bout asking this question, which means if `PageViewItem` is a scrollable widget, then Is not possible to scroll that @RobertSandberg

Comment: Okey, understood.

Comment: Can you add a little more context to this question please? are you looking to stop PageView.builder to not take any clicks at all?

Comment: Question is not clear, what are you willing to achieve? only the fixed card to be clickable or every card in the ListView to be clickable?

Comment: its very interesting that inkwell's onhover not working without adding ontap

Answer (score 0):

That's because top widget in the stack, stack works as a layers, the last child in the `children` list will be the greatest `zIndex` one, so any widget below it is not accessible, you need to `bring it to front` to activate the click, swap the children and making the `InkWell`'s positioned Widget the last child in the children will solve your issue

```
Stack(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 250,
      child: PageView.builder(
        padEnds: false,
        controller: _controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Opacity(
            opacity: index <= _firstItemIndex ? 0 : 1,
            child: PageViewItem(
              index: index,

              width: _itemWidth,
              url: model[index],

            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: model.length,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: _itemWidth,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => debugPrint("clicked"), ///this part not works
            child: PageViewItem(
              index: _firstItemIndex,
              width: _itemWidth,
              url: model[_firstItemIndex],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: you have to run that code before, because `Positioned.fill(` is a copy of widget and if you bring this widget to top  so you can lose view pager

Comment: please remove your answer I want to change my question

Comment: Your issue is `onTap` is not working, did you try my solution? did it work? because I tried it and it did, I believe that your `InkWell` must be in the each card so every card has a different `url` to launch

Comment: Of course, your suggestion does not  work, It doesn't matter onTap working, you have to consider another part of the code works correctly or not, whit your suggestion we lose pageview completely.

Comment: What are you willing to achieve? because that's how stack works, if a layers covers what underneath it and it will not be accessible by user's gesture

Comment: you should run reference. you can understand what is a problem with your suggestion. but briefly, in that code, the last page of page view is shown in a single widget and the pageview opacity becomes 0. If you change the position of this widget to below, this widget completely will cover the view pager and you cant use swap again.

Comment: Yes I know, but what exactly do you want to achieve? only the sticking widget to be clickable or every card in the screen? you did not mention that in your question